# JUNIT HAMCREST cannot find symbol assertThat(java.lang.Long, org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Long>)

Tags: junit, compilation, hamcrest

So I have a simple entity:

```
//imports
....
@Entity
@Table(name="ratings")
public class Rating {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    public Long getId() {
            return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
    }

    ....
}
```

Test:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

....
@Test
public void shouldCreateARating() throws Exception {
    Rating expected = createdRating;
    assertThat(existingRating.getId(), is(1L));
}
...
```

But when I try to compile, I get this compilation error:

```
[ERROR] /c:/limits/src/test/java/hello/RatingsControllerTest.java:[170,33] 
c:\limits\src\test\java\hello\RatingsControllerTest.java:170: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertThat(java.lang.Long,org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Long>)
location: class hello.RatingsControllerTest
```

I checked and `is(T value)` exists, and `assertThat(T actual, org.hamcrest.Matcher<T> matcher)` exist and are imported... so what is going on here? How can I test that a Long has the value I expect if combining the is and assertThat for Long generates a compilation error?

An explanation of why I am testing the get id --- it is a nested object that I save in setup() and its getId() value comes up as null in the test, even though I know that I save it (which hibernate generates an id for).

Making me feel like an idiot.

Comment: Could you please add the static import for assertThat to your Test code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the most recent version of Hamcrest (1.3), the [`Matchers`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html) class doesn't have any `assertThat` methods on it.

You need to static import the [MatcherAssert](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/MatcherAssert.html) class:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

for me I have to import

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
```